# Promise pending; promise function wont do any of the callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm calling the `post('/audit')` and then calling the `getSignature (Promise) function`, which returns the body of the `signature` to print out (with `console.log(audit_signature)`. However, my `Promise` remains `pending` and my `audit_signature` remains undefined. What is causing the issue with the promise and the audit_signature? How do I fix it?

---

(error):

```
start /audit
[stdout] jwtPayload: { description: 'admin',
[stdout]   id: '1508959916',
[stdout]   signature: '4d4a542f-d738-4736-8df5-84575b4d90fd' }
[stdout] ids:  4d4a542f-d738-4736-8df5-84575b4d90fd
[stdout] start: getSignature
[stdout] getAudit: Promise { <pending> }
[stdout] audit_signature: undefined
[stdout] start: responseWithJSON
```

---

(server.js)

```
 function getSignature(uuid){
    console.log('start getSignature');
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        request.post({
            url: `http://${ksiIP}:${ksiPort}/KsiProxy/rest/util/getSignature`, 
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization' : 'Basic Og=='
            }, json: {'uuid': uuid}
        }), function(error, response, body){
            console.log(error);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(body);

            if(error || (response.statusCode != 200)){
                return reject((error ? error : body));
            }
            if(body.resultcode != 0){
                console.log("Error: " + requestResult.info);
                console.log("Asset could not be verified.");
                return reject(new Error(body.info));
            }
            if(response == 'undefined') {
                console.log('ksi unavailable');
                return reject(error);
            }
            //add identification as well
            resolve(body.signature);
            //resolve('resolve is here');
        }
    })      
}

dcServer.post('/audit', function(req,res){ 
    console.log('start /audit'); 
    if(req.jwtPayload.description != "admin"){
        respondWithJSON(401, 401, "Not authorised for this functionality.", res);
        return;
    }
    let toAudit = req.jwtPayload.signature; 
    var audit_signature;
    console.log('jwtPayload:', req.jwtPayload);
    console.log("ids: ", toAudit);

    let failed = 0;//counter to increase if signatures couldnt be retreived. 

    var getAudit = getSignature(toAudit).then( 
                (result) => {return audit_signature = result;} ,
                (error) => {
                        failed++;
                        audit_signature = 'unavailable';
                        console.log(error);
        });
    console.log('getAudit:', getAudit);
    console.log('audit_signature:', audit_signature);

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

`getAudit`  is a Promise and when you print it you will see `getAudit: Promise { <pending> }`
and `getSignature` is async so you have to wait until the promise resolves and print `audit_signature` like this :

```
 var getAudit = getSignature(toAudit).then( 
                (result) => {return audit_signature = result;} ,
                (error) => {
                        failed++;
                        audit_signature = 'unavailable';
                        console.log(error);
        });

    getAudit.then(audit_signature =>{
        console.log('audit_signature:', audit_signature);
    })
```

Comment: With your suggested addition. It doesn't change anything, i.e. the console.log(audit_signature) in the getAudit.then(() fn never gets called.

Comment: And audit_signature remains undefined

Comment: make sure that `body.signature` isn't undefined, and why you said that `getAudit.then` is never gets called ??

Comment: I said getAudit.then() is never called because the console is never displayed.

Comment: so how did you know that `console.log('audit_signature:', audit_signature);` remains undefined ?